# AD HOC SQL Query region within APEX Web App

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-apex, adhoc

I'm trying to create an ad hoc sql text area to execute any query an end user would type in. 
I'm receiving the below error message:
1 error has occurred•ORA-06550: line 5, column 1: PLS-00372: In a procedure, RETURN statement cannot contain an expression ORA-06550: line 5, column 1: PL/SQL: Statement ignored

I created an item for the query area P2_X
and a Button to execute it.

```
DECLARE
v_sql   VARCHAR2 (4000);
BEGIN
v_sql := :P2_X;
return v_sql;
END;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: I created a classic report as a region and selected generic columns and received this:failed to parse SQL query: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist There are also no return of values. How would I change this to a execute immediate command that shows it's not null?

Comment: If you're allowing users to execute arbitrary SQL, be aware (and very afraid) of the potential for SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 1):

This does work.  The code you show goes in the source of a SQL report region.  You also need to select "Generic columns":
[image]

Comment: I created a process and put it in the process previously. When I tried to place it in the Region source for the Report I received the below error message: 1 error has occurred•
Query cannot be parsed, please check the syntax of your query. (ORA-20001: Query must begin with SELECT or WITH)
 (Go to error)

Comment: That's because as I said: you also need to select "Generic columns" radio button when creating the region.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm new to APEX as of 3 weeks ago. I will try to add that too.

Comment: Could you possibly tell me how to do that?

Comment: I created a classic report as a region and selected generic columns and received this:failed to parse SQL query:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

There are also no return of values. I really appreciate the assistance you are providing.

Comment: Also, how would I alter this to use an execute immediate statement that is not null?

Comment: The table you select from has to be visible to the "parsing schema" of the application (look at the application properties).  So you may need to do `grant select on my.table to parsingschema;`

Comment: "how would I alter this to use an execute immediate statement that is not null?" - sorry I don't understand that question, can you clarify?